# slick2d integers and keyboard inputs

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm trying to make an app for my java project using slick2d.

My app is a game (I don't really want to explain the details, it's not really relevant to the question). But basically I want to add 1 integer when I press an assigned key (for example `'k'`). So when I press `k`, the integer add lots of value when it's supposed to be only 1. I think it has to do with `int delta`? Here is my code:

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws   SlickException {  
    Input input = gc.getInput();   
    if (clickPic[0] == true) {  
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_K)) {  
            energy++;  
        }  
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_F)) {  
            life--;  
        }  
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)) {  
            life--;  
        }  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it simply don't add next value until key is released. Add flag and clear it when key is up.

```
if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_K) && !energyPressed) {
    energy++;
    energyPressed = true;
}
if (!input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_K)) {
    energyPressed = false;
}
```

Declare boolean energyPressed on top of your class. This will work.

Comment: thank you very much! it worked. now i can proceed with my project.